# Read line, seperate words by delimiter, write each word on new line, then move on to the next line

Tags: c#, streamreader

A bit of a long title but I'll explain it here.

I have a text file named `sample.txt`

**sample.txt**

```
"105"|2015-01-01 00:00:00|"500"|John Smith"|"Facebook"|"Ohio"|"(555) 555-5555"
"110"|2016-05-20 01:40:00|"550"|David K"|"Twitter"|"Missouri"|"(555) 555-5555"
```

My goal is to read this file, seperate the words by the delimiter and spit out each of the fields on a new line. I have managed to do that but I cannot figure out how to make it move to the next line.

Currently it does what I want it to do, but only for the first line. I assumed `line = sr.ReadLine()` would move to the next set but it doesn't.

```
String line;
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\ME\\Documents\\sample.txt");

    line = sr.ReadLine();
    char delimiterChar = '|';

    while (line != null)
    {
        string[] words = line.Split(delimiterChar);
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            line = sr.ReadLine();
         }
     }

     sr.Close();
     Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing Finally Block");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `line = sr.ReadLine();` out for the `foreach` loop. Right now it is reading a new line for each string in the first line, which consumes the rest of the input.

It should be immediately after the `foreach` loop, but still within the `while` loop.